# Update React - Generic type 'ValueType' problems

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

This morning I had this error in my react application: SharedArrayBuffer will require cross-origin isolation as of M91, around May 2021.

I saw that react must be updated, that's what I did and I went to version `17.0.2 of react-dom and react`.

But I only get errors like this:

```
TypeScript error in ... : Generic type 'ValueType' requires 2 type argument(s).  TS2314
```

I have tried to solve them, but when I solve one error, another comes up and it goes on and on.

*Note: I get the project from a former developer who did not provide me with any doc and the code is not commented on so my radius of action is very small*

Comment: typescript will show the file name & line number in which error is happening. Please look at that code or post it here.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how, but I rollbacked the project from git.I changed react and react-dom version in package.json and now I haven't any errors...